# Tic Tac Toe- finding the winner in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

So I'm creating a Tic Tac Toe game in React. right now I'm trying to figure out the logic of player wins in my app component. I already have the possible moves that they can win as well as the array. For testing purposes, I try an if statement for **midWin**, but it seems to not work. Can some tell me why it is not working? I'm not able to show my code on JS fiddle for some strange reason, but here is my code:

```
let data = {
    "box":[
        [ "", "", "" ],
        [ "", "", "" ],
        [ "", "", "" ]
    ],
    "players": ['X','O']
}
class DataStore {
    constructor(data, players) {
        //store that data in the object
        this.data = data;
        this.players = players;
        //empty array for our watchers
        //watchers are objects that want to be informed about when the data changes
        this.registeredWatchers = [];
    }
    //add a new watcher to the list
    register(watcher) {
        this.registeredWatchers.push(watcher);
    }
    setCrop(newDataState, row, col) {
        //update data
        this.data[row][col] = newDataState;
        //inform all watching objects..
        this.registeredWatchers.map((watcher) => {
            watcher.dataUpdated();
        })
    }
    reset() {
        // this.data = data;
    }
}
class Dispatcher {
    constructor() {
        this.registeredHandlers = []; //D:
    }
    register(callback) {
        this.registeredHandlers.push(callback);
    }
    dispatch(action) {
        //call every method in our registered handlers array
        //with this action as an input
        this.registeredHandlers.map((handler) => {
            //call that individual function in the array..
            handler(action);
        })
    }
    reset(val){

    }
}
class BoxComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className="box"
                onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                <span>{this.props.type}</span>
            </div>);
    }
    handleClick() {
        //try a test dispatch
        if(this.props.type.length > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            boxDispatcher.dispatch({ type: "pick", row: this.props.rowNum, col: this.props.colNum});
        }
    }
}
class GridComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Player {this.props.turn} is next.</p>
                {
                    //loop through all the  rows...
                    this.props.box.map((row, rowNum) => {
                        //and write them out to the page..
                        return (<div className="row">
                            {
                                row.map((cropEntry, colNum) => {
                                    return <BoxComponent type={cropEntry}  rowNum={rowNum} colNum={colNum} turn={rowNum}/>
                                })
                            }
                        </div>);
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        //make sure this stays a react component
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            turn: boxDataStore.players[0],
            box: boxDataStore.data
        }
        //ensure we're listening to the data store
        boxDataStore.register(this);
    }
    dataUpdated() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            box: boxDataStore.data,
            // turn: cropDataStore.players,
            turn: prevState.turn === 'X'
                ? boxDataStore.players[1]
                : boxDataStore.players[0]
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // renders out the whole data on the board
            <div>
                <h1>Tic Tac Toe </h1>
                <button onClick={this.resetBoard.bind(this)}>Reset Board</button>
                <button onClick={this.checkWinner.bind(this)}>Check Winner</button>
                <GridComponent box={this.state.box} turn={this.state.turn} />
            </div>
        );
    }
    // rests the data back to the orginal state which is  from the let data
    resetBoard() {
        const newBoxData = [
            [ "", "", "" ],
            [ "", "", "" ],
            [ "", "", "" ]
        ]
        boxDataStore.data = newBoxData;
        this.setState({
            box: boxDataStore.data
        })

    }
    // end data that tells the update

    // events that help users find out who the winner or the losers
    checkWinner() {


        //vertical wins
        const topWin = [
            this.state.box["0"]["0"],
            this.state.box["0"]["1"],
            this.state.box["0"]["2"]
        ];

        const midWin = [
            this.state.box["1"]["0"],
            this.state.box["1"]["1"],
            this.state.box["1"]["2"]
        ];

        const bottom = [
            this.state.box["2"]["0"],
            this.state.box["2"]["1"],
            this.state.box["2"]["2"]
        ];
        // vertical wins end.

        //horizontal wins
        const horizMid = [
            this.state.box["0"]["1"],
            this.state.box["1"]["1"],
            this.state.box["2"]["1"]
        ];

        const horizleft = [
            this.state.box["0"]["2"],
            this.state.box["1"]["2"],
            this.state.box["2"]["2"]
        ];

        const horizright = [
            this.state.box["0"]["0"],
            this.state.box["1"]["1"],
            this.state.box["2"]["2"]
        ];
        //horiztanl end

        const diagonalright = [
            this.state.box["0"]["0"],
            this.state.box["1"]["1"],
            this.state.box["2"]["2"]
        ];

        function identical(array) {
            for(let i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
                if(array[i] === array[i+1]) {
                    return true;

                }
            }
        };

        if(identical(midWin)) {
            alert('midWin')
        }

    }
}
//start of app
var boxDispatcher = new Dispatcher();
var boxDataStore = new DataStore(data.box, data.players);
boxDispatcher.register((action) => {
    if(boxDataStore.registeredWatchers["0"].state.turn == "X") {
        //actually waint to handle it
        boxDataStore.setCrop('X', action.row, action.col);
    } else {
        boxDataStore.setCrop('O', action.row, action.col);
    }
})
ReactDOM.render(<App data={boxDataStore.data} />, document.querySelector("#app"));
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with identical function. I have corrected the function.

```
        function identical(array) {

        // Check if any of the box is blank. if yes then no need to check the win
        if(array.some(function(element){return element===""})){
            return false;
        }

        let winFlag = true;

        for(let i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
            if(array[i] !== array[i+1]) {
                winFlag = false;
            }
        }
        return winFlag;
    }
```

Please check JS fiddle for the details -
https://jsfiddle.net/abhijeet_srivastava/wx2tq713/11/